# Preloading game assets (images) for latter / instant use

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a game ui that requires high amount of images that also total to relatively big size (~30mb). I've been caching them to the disc via service workers, but some of them are ~3mb in size and even when they come from disc there is noticeable delay before they appear (a flick of sorts).

After some research on other games it seems that common practice is to preload these into memory and break it down logically i.e only preload assets required for specific level.

How would one preload images into memory with javascript and keep track of what is still being loaded or has been evicted from memory? Note that elements that display these images can appear on page dynamically i.e. not be there initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to preload it. Also having the images somewhere in the DOM would prevent the browser to start garbage collecting the asset.

Different strategy would obviously be to

- cut your assets up in to multiple assets
- to use the `webp` image format
- to further compress/downsize them (ie. only load highres if the device has a highDPI display)